# Regex to match domain without subfolder

Tags: regex

Currently I'm using the following regex to match a url

```
/(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,63}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?/
```

I'm wondering how I can modify it to only match on domain names without subfolders.

For example

```
http://thisiatest.com/ -> Good
thisisatest.com -> Good
http://thisiatest.com -> Good
http://thisisatest.com/folder/ -> Bad
thisisatest.com/folder/ -> Bad
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your regex can be simplified to this:

```
^(?:\S+://)?[^/]+/?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nG7kM9/1)

Answer (score 0):

The following regex is also worth a try:

```
(?:https?://)?([^/\s]+\.[^/\s]+)/?(?:\s|$)
```

[Here is the Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/nG7kM9/3)

**Explanation:**

```
(?:https?://)?          non-capturing group starts
                        match http:// or https:// zero or one time
(                       capturing group starts
[^/\s]+                 match characters except / and space
                        1 or more times
\.                      literally match dot (.)
[^/\s]+                 match characters except / and space
                        1 or more times 
)                       capturing group ends
/?                      match / zero or one time    
(?:\s|$)                non-capturing group
                        assert any white space or end of line
```